# Outputing query result stored in a Multi dimentional array ( getting Array to string conversion)

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am performing a select query from the database and store the result into an array like so:
`$res[] = $row;`. Then in my view i get: 
Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs ...

In my view

```
  <?php foreach($res as $PARENT_CAT_CODE => $PARENT_CAT_DESC): ?>
  <option value="<?= $PARENT_CAT_CODE;  ?>"><?= $PARENT_CAT_DESC; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

var_dump($res); (Output)

```
array(4) {
      [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["PARENT_CAT_CODE"]=> string(3) "100"
            ["PARENT_CAT_DESC"]=> string(16) "ROUTE COLLECTION"
          }
      [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["PARENT_CAT_CODE"]=> string(1) "1"
            ["PARENT_CAT_DESC"]=> string(5) "SHOES"
      }
      [2]=>
          array(2) {
            ["PARENT_CAT_CODE"]=> string(1) "4"
            ["PARENT_CAT_DESC"]=> string(41) "ΑΝΤΑΛΛΑΚΤΙΚΑ ΟΧΗΜΑΤΩΝ"
          }
      [3]=>
          array(2) {
            ["PARENT_CAT_CODE"]=> string(1) "6"
            ["PARENT_CAT_DESC"]=> string(10) "ΒΑΦΕΣ"
      }

    }
```

the query:

```
<?php
$categories_PST = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT DISTINCT PARENT_CAT_CODE,PARENT_CAT_DESC FROM V_SCT_ITEM ORDER BY PARENT_CAT_DESC');

oci_execute($categories_PST);

while ( $row = oci_fetch_array($categories_PST) )
 {
    $res[] = $row;
  }
```

Comment: please write the part of code with $res variable

Comment: which is the output of `var_dump($res);`

Comment: @GiacomoM it's already in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You looped it wrong,

`$val` is an array which you will get in loop with data you are asking for to populate in option tag. This should work.

When you loop 2D array in a single loop, its instance/loop val I can say, will have immediate next level of array and you can use it as below you want.

```
<?php foreach ($res as $val): ?>
    <option value="<?= $val['PARENT_CAT_CODE']; ?>" >  <?= $val['PARENT_CAT_DESC']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: `Notice:  Undefined index: $PARENT_CAT_DESC`

Comment: @GragasIncoming Made changes. Have a look now

Comment: It works! Can you add more details and explain for the others? Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look now.